# Populate Custom Fields in a Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, metabox, post-meta

I want to set up a basic 'post rating' system for my site - I don't want to use a plugin - so I want to add the custom field 'rating' to each new custom post and populate this field with the number 1.

Is this possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way? Did a lot of searching a found not much, `add_post_meta()` ? I'm not sure where that would go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do that with hooking a simple function to `save_post` hook

```
add_action('save_post','my_rating_field');
function my_rating_field($post_id){
    global $post;
        // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
        // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
            return;

        // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
        // because save_post can be triggered at other times
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return;
        // Check post type
        if ($post->post_type != "YOUR_POST_TYPE_NAME")
            return;

        // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    $rating = get_post_meta($post_id,'rating',true);
    //if field not exists create it and give it the value of one
    if (empty($rating) || !isset($rating)){
        update_post_meta($post_id,'rating',1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. nice code. I had to comment out the `if ( !wp_verify_nonce` line - I am calling this from the theme's functions.php and not a plugin. Is there a way I can verify authorisation in this case? thanks